# How to find a certain link under a tr that is underneath several identical trs

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Another problem getting to a particular portion of the HTML to click a link.  I need to click the  link that is above the Classify Item #, IFW #QA GM 04012014 1424-1, Supplier One

The only part of the TD that I know is "QA GM 04012014 1424".  I can get to the table by doing a:

//*[@id='openTasksTable']/tbody

What I'm left with then is an unknown number of TD's all with the same ID.  I'm not sure how to find the proper one from that point.

Code:

```
<table id="openTasksTable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="evenRow tableControlDataRow twTableTR">
                <td>
                    <a href="../teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=t453156" target="_blank">Run Task</a>
                </td>
                <td>Classify Item #, IFW #QA GM 04012014 0911-1, Supplier One</td>
                <td>Apr 24, 2014</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="oddRow tableControlDataRow twTableTR">
                <td>
                    <a href="../teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=t453157" target="_blank">Run Task</a>
                </td>
                <td>Classify Item #, IFW #QA GM 04012014 1012-1, Supplier One</td>
                <td>Apr 24, 2014</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="evenRow tableControlDataRow twTableTR">
                <td>
                    <a href="../teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=t453158" target="_blank">Run Task</a>
                </td>
                <td>Classify Item #, IFW #QA GM 04012014 1414-1, Supplier One</td>
            <td>Apr 24, 2014</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="oddRow tableControlDataRow twTableTR">
                <td>
                <a href="../teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=t453159" target="_blank">Run Task</a>
            </td>
                <td>Classify Item #, IFW #QA GM 04012014 1420-1, Supplier One</td>
                <td>Apr 24, 2014</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="evenRow tableControlDataRow twTableTR">
                <td>
                <a href="../teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=t453160" target="_blank">Run Task</a>
                </td>
                <td>Classify Item #, IFW #QA GM 04012014 1422-1, Supplier One</td>
            <td>Apr 24, 2014</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="oddRow tableControlDataRow twTableTR">
                <td>
                    <a href="../teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=t453161" target="_blank">Run Task</a>
                </td>
                <td>Classify Item #, IFW #QA GM 04012014 1424-1, Supplier One</td>
                <td>Apr 24, 2014</td>
            </tr>
```

Thanks!
Greg

Comment: You could create a variable "td_counts" = 0, for each td: td_counts += 1, if "Classify Item" in td, desired_td_count = td_count - 1

Comment: I've updated the code to give more info.  Not sure the above would work to get me to the href I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following xpath should work for you:

```
//td[contains(text(),'QA GM 04012014 1424')]/..//a
```

It will find only the `<a>` which is in the same `<tr>` with `<td>` you mentioned.

Comment: That gives me an invalid XPath error.  And trying the full thing:    //*[@id='openTasksTable']/tbody/td[contains(text(),'QA GM 04012014 1424')]/..//a        Also gives me an invalid XPath error.

Comment: That was a typo in it. I've just updated it. Try again plz. Also it is no need to add anything to the begining of it.

Comment: I've corrected mine also.  Gives No matching Nodes.  Can't find it using that.

Comment: If you want to use full path (But this is not necessary). You should use `//*[@id='openTasksTable']//tbody//td[contains(text(),'QA GM 04012014 1424')]/..//a` It is `//` instead of `/` to search not only direct children of nodes.

Comment: But the `//*[@id='openTasksTable']//tbody` part is not necessary here, it is better to remove it. Then xpath will not depend on id of the <table>. If you won't remove it, it will not work in case of changes of this id.

Comment: A way to do the same thing without backtracking: `//tr[td[contains(text(),'QA GM 04012014 1424')]]//a`

Comment: Wow, much cleaner.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case I do have to have the <table>.  There are 6 other places in other parts of this code that also have that text in them.  If I removed it, it would take the first td that contained 'QA GM 04012014 1424' which would be the wrong one.  I didn't include the full source as it's pages and pages long.